# Search elasticsearch all content from especific source

Tags: elasticsearch

i want to know if it is possible to search all content from a specific _source in elasticsearch.

for example i have this:

```
{
"_shards":{
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
},
"hits":{
    "total" : 1,
    "hits" : [
        {
            "_index" : "twitter",
            "_type" : "tweet",
            "_id" : "1", 
            "_source" : {
                "user" : "kimchy",
                "postDate" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
                "message" : "trying out Elastic Search"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

i want query all users from source without specifying the name.

for eg: something similar in SQL is like this

```
SELECT * user from twitter
```

and with that give all users

thanks and sorry for my bad english

edit:
i want search only for the source. 
i give you an example, i have a source who store random word, sometimes store, sometimes not. i want to search for this source only when have new words.

the plan is verify from last 10 minutes if in my specific source have something new, if not, i don't care

Comment: I don't really understand your question an your sql command confuses me. Considering that Twitter is your table and user, postdate and message are you columns, do you want to select the user column from the table ? Try giving a more concrete example with expected result from a data set.

Comment: in my elasticsearch exist on source who receive information, i want verify periodical if this source have any new information. i want to check 10 in 10 minutes if this source have anything new

Comment: ok i fugured out how to do it, i just need put timestamp on the search, on this
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_search'

i want with this line search from last 10 minutes, its opossible?

Answer (score 0):

You can just:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_search'
```

That by default will return `10` documents.  You can sipecify a `size`:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_search?size=BIGNUM'
```

Or you can use `scrool`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i want search only for the source. 
i give you an exemple, i have a source who store random word, sometimes store, sometimes not. i want to search for this source only when have new words.

the plan is verify from last 10 minutes if in my especific source have something new, ig not, i dont care